# Change theme globally in vuetify next

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

Im trying to change the theme of my entire project.

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/lib/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/lib/directives';

export default createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: {
        DefaultTheme: 'dark'
    }
});
```

This works fine, and changes the entire theme, but when I try to access the global variable of theme that is located in vuetify. it does not exist.
I do the following:

```js
import { computed, ref, watch, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

...

const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance()

...

console.log(internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$vuetify);
```

this code gives me an empty globalProperty.

[image]

I did the same thing in vue 2 and it works fine.
When I try to reach the global variable and change the dark theme it does  work.

`this.$vuetify.theme.isDark`

[image]